# How to set value in shelve

Tags: python, python-3.x, shelve

I want to store dictionary in shelve and also want to put data in that. How can i do that?

```
import shelve

s = shelve.open("test")
s['flag'] = {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit values directly, so you have to update a copy and then reset it:

```
import shelve

s = shelve.open("test")
s['flag'] = {}
temp = s['flag']
temp['foo'] = 'bar'
s['flag'] = temp
```

you cannot do

```
s['flag']['foo'] = 'bar'
```

directly because `s['flag']` returns a copy

Comment: Why It is not working when I deploy my flask app to heroku? It is giving me an error : _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

Comment: @BhaveshMevada i think your program terminated before the shelve was closed properly, that will corrupt it. make sure to close your shelve properly before terminating the application. you'll have to delete the corrupted one.

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried to store the data in shelve and even update it.
It's working.
If this is not your issue. Then Please elaborate

```
import shelve

s = shelve.open("test")
s['flag'] = {"sda":11}
data = s["flag"]
print(data)
s['flag'] = {"sda":12}
data = s["flag"]
print(data)
s.close()
```